# How to download file to local machine instead of cloud desktop in Java?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, download, cloud

I have a file on S3 which I am downloading using a s3 handler. It gets downloaded to the cloud desktop (where my code is located). I have used the following to get the path:

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File file = new File(home+"/Downloads/" + fileName + ".txt");
```

I want the file to be downloaded to the local machine instead of the cloud desktop. Is there a way to route the file from cloud desktop to local? What can be done to get the file on the local machine instead? Any ideas?

Comment: Run the code locally instead of remotely?

Comment: Yeah I was just trying to know if there is any way to run it on cloud and download file locally?

Comment: File gets saved to the cloud desktop where the server is located. If I want it to get stored locally on client's machine, would I have to stream it there? How to do that?